# unconditional expectation derived from conditional binomial, Poisson and exponential.

Tags: probability, expectation, conditional-expectation

X|Y~Binomial(Y,p), Y|Z~Poisson(Z), Z~exponential(b),where p and b are constants. What is the E(X) and Var (X)

My way to solve it to to find the joint pdf of (Y|Z) and Z so we can have the marginal (unconditionally)Y. Similar get the marginal of X to get the E(X) and VAR(X). Is there a simpler way to solve it?

Comment: Distributions, joint or otherwise, are offtopic here: note that $E(X|Y)=pY$ hence $E(X)=pE(Y)$, and $E(Y|Z)=Z$ hence $E(Y)=E(Z)=1/b$ and $E(X)=p/b$. Likewise, Var$(X|Y)=p(1-p)Y$ hence Var$(X)=E($Var$(X|Y))+$Var$(E(X|Y))=p(1-p)E(Y)+p^2$Var$(Y)$. Likewise, Var$(Y)=E($Var$(Y|Z))+$Var$(E(Y|Z))=E(Z)+$Var$(Z)=1/b+1/b^2$. Finally, Var$(X)=p(1-p)/b+p^2(1/b+1/b^2)=p/b+p^2/b^2$. (This assumes that $b$ is the parameter of $Z$, that is, that $E(Z)=1/b$.) The goal of the exercise is that you learn the [law of total variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance).

Comment: I'm commenting here to remind myself to look at this later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the formulas $\mathbb{E}(\mathrm{Bin}(n,p)) = np$ and $\mathbb{V}\mathrm{ar}(\mathrm{Bin}(n,p)) = np(1 - p),$ you can get that $\mathbb{E}(X\mid Y) = Yp$ and $\mathbb{V}\mathrm{ar}(X\mid Y) = Yp(1 - p).$ Henceforth, $\mathbb{E}(X) = \mathbb{E}(Y)p$ and $\mathbb{V}\mathrm{ar}(X) = \mathbb{V}\mathrm{ar}(Y)p^2(1 - p)^2.$ Suffices to find $\mathbb{E}(Y)$ and $\mathbb{V}\mathrm{ar}(Y).$ Similarly, $\mathbb{E}(Y\mid Z) = Z,$ so $\mathbb{E}(Y) = \dfrac{1}{b}.$ To calculate $\mathbb{V}\mathrm{ar}(Y)$ one needs to be a bit careful, $\mathbb{V}\mathrm{ar}(Y) = \mathbb{E}(Y^2) - \mathbb{E}(Y)^2 = \mathbb{E}(Y^2) - \dfrac{1}{b^2}$ and $\mathbb{E}(Y^2) = \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(Y^2\mid Z)) = \int\limits_0^\infty dz \mathbb{E}(Y^2\mid Z=z) be^{-bz}$,
and since $Y\mid Z=z \sim \mathrm{Pois}(z),$ it follows that $\mathbb{E}(Y^2\mid Z=z) = z + z^2,$ whence $\mathbb{E}(Y^2) = \int\limits_0^\infty dz (z + z^2)be^{-bz} =\dfrac{1}{b} + \dfrac{2}{b^2}.$ Substitute back and you get all you wanted.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the \mid command